# Print out many rows from reader

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, asp.net-3.5

The following will just print out 1 row from the database

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection connection;
    SqlCommand command;
    SqlDataReader reader;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connString"]))
        {
            using (command = new SqlCommand("select col1, col2 from table1 where id = @id", connection))
            {
                command.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int, 3).Value = 1;
                connection.Open();

                using (reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    reader.Read();
                    Div1.InnerHtml = reader["col1"].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What needs to be done here so it prints out all rows returned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here:

```
using (reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        sb.Append(reader["col1"].ToString());
    }
    Div1.InnerHtml = sb.ToString();
}
```

Also since you are instantiating your connection objects inside the method you don't really need to make them as private fields:

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connString"]))
        using (var command = new SqlCommand("select col1, col2 from table1 where id = @id", connection))
        {
            command.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int, 3).Value = 1;
            connection.Open();

            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                var sb = new StringBuilder();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    sb.Append(reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("col1")));
                }
                Div1.InnerHtml = sb.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Put the Read call in a while loop:

```
using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
   var builder = new StringBuilder();
   while (reader.Read()) 
   {
     builder.Append(reader["col1"].ToString());
   }
   Div1.InnerHtml = builder.ToString();
}
```

As an aside, you appear to have a page behind file, whose primary concern should be the page, that is accessing the database. You may wish to look into SOLID principles when designing classes. In this instance the Single Responsibility principle is being violated. Adhering to these principles aids maintainability, code re-use and makes refactoring far easier.

Comment: Not totally sure what you mean by your last sentence about horizontal slices?